# How Do I Build a Quantile Regression Model with GradientBoostingRegressor from sklearn?

Tags: python, boosting, quantile-regression

I am building a quantile regression model using scikit-learn's GradientBoostingRegressor algorithm.

I was going to use GridSearchCV for hyperparameter optimization.

Two questions:

1. Does it make sense to use gridsearchcv given that I am looking at quantile regression rather than mean-based regression?
2. If yes, what should I be using for the scoring parameter for GridSearchCV?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, it makes perfect sense to use `GridSearchCV`. It is very reasonable way to choose hyper-parameters.
2. The scoring parameter should correspond to the quantile of interest $\alpha$. The mean quantile loss $\text{MQL}_{\alpha} $ for a particular quantile $\alpha$ is: $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \rho_\alpha(y_i - \hat{y}_i)$. Here $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is a constant and the check function $\rho_{\alpha}(r)$ is: $r(\alpha - \mathbf 1_{r<0})$ or more descriptively: $\mathbf 1_{r<0} (1-\alpha) |r| + \mathbf 1_{r \geq 0} (\alpha) |r|$, with $r$ being our residual $r = y_i - \hat{y}_i$ and $\mathbf 1$ being the indicator function. (CV.SE has some great answer if you want to see more details on the matter [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88387/quantile-regression-estimator-formula/88961#88961) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384909/formulating-quantile-regression-as-linear-programming-problem/384913#384913)).

So our $\text{MQL}_{\alpha} $ loss function would be something like:

```
def mqloss(y_true, y_pred, alpha):  
  if (alpha > 0) and (alpha < 1):
    residual = y_true - y_pred 
    return np.mean(residual * (alpha - (residual<0)))
  else:
    return np.nan
```

Some minor final things to note:

1. we would have to use of [`make_scorer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) functionality from `sklearn.metrics` to create this custom loss function. We could then pass it to `GridSearchCV` as the scoring parameter.
   (i.e. some like: `mqloss_scorer = make_scorer(mqloss, alpha=0.90)`)
2. we would have to refit our model/rerun `GridSearchCV` for each different choice of $\alpha$. This is inline with the `sklearn`'s example of using the quantile regression to generate [prediction intervals for  gradient boosting regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_quantile.html).
3. our choice of $\alpha$ for `GradientBoostingRegressor`'s quantile loss should coincide with our choice of $\alpha$ for `mqloss`. Otherwise we are training our GBM again one quantile but we are evaluating it against another. It is doable, but most likely incoherent. :)

Comment: Here is the problem - I have used GridSearchCV separately for values of α = 0.5 and 0.75. 
 The resulting models give me higher predictions on test data in many cases for the 0.5 model compared with the 0.75 model.  I would have expected higher results in all cases from the 0.75 model.  Is there a fix for this?  I am thinking that maybe the hyperparameters need to be the same for both models?

Comment: While unfortunate, there is no way of direct fixing this aside having a "better model". Maybe the modelling fitting process is inappropriate or maybe the test set is too small or non-representative. To that effect, as the two models have different objective functions  we would not expect the same hyperparameters. In general, you do not comment how large your sample is but smaller samples (<10K) often lead to poor quantile estimates. GBMs while great are not terribly data-efficient. Also maybe you want to check [NGBoost](https://stanfordmlgroup.github.io/projects/ngboost/) as an alternative.